# external javascript function in onclick event

Tags: javascript, wordpress, events, onclick, external

I am using WrodPress 4.0.1.
I have a simple form in a webpage in HTML. 
After the form, I have a button with an onclick event handler, which calls a function to access this form when the button is clicked.
The function that I want to be fired by the onclick event is inside an external javascript file called `group-membership-cost.js`.  The function inside the external JavaScript file is called `groupMembershipCost()`.
My question is: I don't know how to get the onclick event handler to call groupMembershipCost(), which is inside group-membership-cost.js, when the button is clicked.
I have tried using `<button onclick="groupMembershipCost()">` but I get `ReferenceError: groupMembershipCost is not defined`, when I look in my Firebug console.

This is the HTML form

```
<form id="group_membership">
6 - 9 members: <input name="6_9" type="text" /> x $35 per member
10 - 14 members: <input name="10_14" type="text" /> x $30 per member
15 - 19 members: <input name="15_19" type="text" /> x $25 per member</form>
<button onclick="groupMembershipCost()">Calculate total for Group Membership</button>

Total: <span id="total">0</span>
```

I have enqueued the function in functions.php using the following code

```
function group_membership_cost() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'group-membership', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/group-membership-cost.js', array(), '1.0', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'group_membership_cost' );
```

The script is correctly enqueued because when I look at HTML source for the page, I see

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/myTheme/javascript/group-membership-cost.js?ver=1.0'></script>
```

Here is the code from `group-membership-cost.js`

```
function groupMembershipCost() {

var output = document.getElementById("total");

var group1 = document.getElementsByName("6_9")[0].value;

var group2 = document.getElementsByName("10_14")[0].value;

var group3 = document.getElementsByName("15_19")[0].value;


if (group1 != '' && parseInt(group1) != NaN) {
    if (parseInt(group1) < 6) {
        output.innerHTML = "The number of group members in this category must be greater than 5."; 
    }
    else if (parseInt(group1) > 9) {
        output.innerHTML = "The number of group members in this category must be less than 10.";
    }
    else {
        output.innerHTML = parseInt(group1) * 35;
    }
}

else if (group2 != '' && parseInt(group2) != NaN) {
     if (parseInt(group2) < 10) {
        output.innerHTML = "The number of group members in this category must be greater than 9."; 
    }
     else if (parseInt(group2) > 14) {
        output.innerHTML = "The number of group members in this category must be less than 15.";
    }
    else {
        output.innerHTML = parseInt(group2) * 30;
    }
}


else if (group3 != '' && parseInt(group3) != NaN) {
    if (parseInt(group3) < 15) {
        output.innerHTML = "The number of group members in this category must be greater than 14."; 
    }
    else if (parseInt(group3) > 19) {
        output.innerHTML = "The number of group members in this category must be less than 20.";
    }
    else {
        output.innerHTML = parseInt(group3) * 25;
    }
}

else { output.innerHTML = "Please enter the number of people in your group into one of the three boxes above."; }

}
```

I can't figure out why the web page can't access `groupMembershipCost()`, if it is in a .js file that is correctly linked to the page.  If the `group-membership-cost.js` file is correctly linked to the page using WordPress's script enqueueing function, doesn't that make the functions within that JavaScript file available to the HTML document?

Comment: JS is case sensitive, groupMembershipCost and groupmembershipCost are different function names.

Comment: show the contents of your js file

Comment: sorry, it's not a case problem.  The code is always groupMembershipCost().  I just mistyped it here.

Comment: no reason for it not to be working, but try `wp_enqueue_script( 'group-membership', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/group-membership-cost.js');` and the script is being loaded in the head?

Comment: @David do you mean remove the 3 last parameters: array(), '1.0', and false ?

Comment: yes they are unnecessary for the page btw open the file through the link as well, is it up to date? reset your cache if not.

Answer (score 0):

I loaded Wordpress 4.0.1 and was not able to reproduce the problem. This code works for me in Firefox v33 and Chrome v39.

[image: wp-screenshot]

How are you setting things up? I did the following:

1. put the html in the textbox of a page
2. put the wp_enqueue_script function at the very end of

   ../wordpress/wp-content/themes/**yourTheme**/functions.php
3. put the script in

   ../wordpress/wp-content/themes/**yourTheme**/javascript/group-membership-cost.js

Are you using the theme **yourTheme** in your current Wordpress app?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that you couldn't reproduce the problem.  That let me know that the code was basically correct.  I figured out the problem and it makes me feel stupid to admit, but I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well after Adrew said he couldn't reproduce the problem, I felt confident that I had coded it correctly for the most part.  That prompted me to look for "duh" errors.  Sorry for wasting all your guy's time.  If anyone cares, here was the problem....

I went back and looked at the web page, and looked at the page source.  In the page's source code, I clicked on my script's hyperlink, and it opened up an editor containing my script's JavaScript code.  For some reason, the changes that I made previously to my script were not there.

Previously, I had `<script> </script>` tags at the start and end of the `group-membership-cost.js` function that were left over from when I started to try to code all of this inline in the HTML document.  But I removed those tags when i placed the JavaScript code in a .js file.  For some reason, that one change of removing the `<script>` tags didn't save, and it buggered everything naturally.

So I just ftp'd to the server using WinSCP, opened the script file in WinSCP's text editor, and hit the "Reload" icon in the toolbar.  Then I hard refreshed the web page.
Now it works.

Guess I learned nothing but to make sure to hit the "Reload" button in WinSCP's text editor religiously.
Sorry for wasting everyone's time.